# Location API throwing an error on Android

Tags: codenameone

I see this sporadic message on Android devices when using the LocationManager.getLocationManager().setLocationListener() and Tracking GPS location in the App. Please advise if anyone see the same issue

Answer (score 0):

This will happen if you invoke `getCurrentLocation` when there is no location. If you have a location listener and it invoked your callback this will never happen. However, if it still didn't invoke the callback or you didn't bind a listener this can happen.

Comment: Add code to understand and let you fix @shai is right regarding location

Comment: The timer can fire before there's any locations